# How do you add nested fields to a text index in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having trouble adding nested fields to a text index in MongoDB.

The code below adds string fields at the top level to the text index correctly.  The two nested fields "contentright" and "contentfooterhead" that I am trying to add are added but do not index correctly.

[image]

```
var keys = {"name", "subject", "contentright", "contentfooterhead"};

var indexKeys = new IndexKeysBuilder();
indexKeys.Text(keys);

var options = new IndexOptionsBuilder();
options.SetName("testIndex");
options.SetBackground(true);

collection.CreateIndex(indexKeys, options);
```

This is what my text index looks like after the code is run:

[image]

If I run

```
indexKeys.TextAll();
```

which is equivalent to an index of

```
"$**": "text"
```

all the fields are indexed fine, but I don't want to add them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). The paths to your nested fields are `Con.contentright` and `Con.contentfooterhead`.